# ( $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ ) Show that $f$ is riemann integrable and evaluate it. (Use basic definitions)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

- Let $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

  $f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{0} & {x \text { irrational, }} \\ {0} & {x \text { rational, } y \text { irrational, }} \\ {1 / q} & {x \text { rational, } y=p / q \text { in lowest terms. }}\end{array}\right.$

Show that $f$ is integrable and evalute it.

**I couldn't prove it, may you help?**

I took two partition: $P_1=\{0,1/n,2/n,...,1\}$ and $P_2=\{0,1/n,2/n,...,1\}.$ Later I couldn't choose any sub-rectangle.. I could do nothing...

Comment: Start with an enumeration of the rational numbers $r_1,r_2,...$ For convenience you can assume that all rationals with denominator $1$ (in lowest terms) come before the ones with denominator $2$, and then those with denominator $3$ and so on. For each $n$ take a partition such that the points $(r_i,r_j)$, with $i,j\leq n$ are inside squares (with sides parallel to the axes) of side $\epsilon/n$. The rest of the partition can be any way you want. For example, just extend the sides of those squares. Now compute Riemann sums. The lower sums are $0$, since inside any rectangle of the partition ...

Comment: ... there are points with either $x$ or $y$ irrational. The upper Riemann sums can be bounded in the following way. The terms corresponding to the squares enclosing the points $(r_i,r_j)$ with $i,j\leq n$ is bounded by $1$, which is a global bound for the values of the function, times the sum of the areas of those squares. That is $n^2\cdot (\epsilon/n\cdot)^2=\epsilon^2$. The terms corresponding to other rectangles of the partition can be bounded by ... Opps above I meant not $i,j\leq n$, but rather all $i,j$ such that the denominators of $r_i, r_j$ are $\leq n$. ...

Comment: The sum of the terms corresponding to other rectangles can be bounded in the following way: Note that the values of the function on those rectangles are bounded by $1/n$. Therefore, the sum of those terms can be bounded by $1/n $ times the total area of those rectangle. But the total area can be bounded by $1$, which is the area of $[0,1]^2$. Therefore, the upper Riemann sum in this partition is bounded from above by $\epsilon^2+1/n$. Finally, any given partition has a refinement of the form given above.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy your comment(s) is/are essentially the answer to the question. Why did you put them in the comments instead of in the answer section?